# How to compare multiple variables?

Tags: python

So in my code I have 12 variables all of different words, they are pairs (For example red, red, blue, blue, yellow, yellow, green, green, purple, purple, indigo, indigo). However they're in a random order and there is no way to know where they are in the code.

Is there any way to quickly find where the other word of the pair is without a million `if` statements?

This problem is quite hard to describe, but what the code is doing is automating a web game where you must match a French word with and English word so far I have gathered a list of all the words there are to match and I have translated all words to English but now I need to match the French word to its matching English word and then click there to complete the game.

For example:

```
word1 = "Hello"
word2 = "Morning"
word3 = "Hello"
word4 = "Morning"
```

What I want to avoid is going through and using:

```
if word1 == word2:
    click(x, y)
if word1 == word3:
    click(x, y)
```

So as you can imagine doing that for every combination for 12 variables would be a pain.

Here is the browser game if I explained it badly https://quizlet.com/601969734/match

Comment: how about `if word1 in {word2, word3, ...}:`?

Comment: Must you implement your words as separate variables? Couldn't you just embed them in a list or dictionary? That would make the solution as easy as using any()

Comment: `collections.Counter([word1, word2, ...])` can tell you quickly if you have any duplicates.

Comment: I recommend storing your words in a [data structure](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) instead of a series of numbered variables.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I greatly appreciate it

Answer (score 2):

You can put the variables in a list and then use loops:

```
word_list = [word1, word2, word3, word4]

for ai, a in enumerate(word_list):
    for bi, b in enumerate(word_list):
        if ai < bi and a == b:
            click(a, b)
```

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, you need to learn how to use data collections.  Your question should be based on a list of strings, not individual variables.

```
word_list = ["Hello", "Morning", "Hello", "Morning"]
```

From here, it's a simple matter to use built-in functions to find matching items:

```
for idx, word in enumerate(word_list):
    match = index(word, word_list[idx+1:])  # Look for word in the rest of the list
    if match > 0:
         # you have matching words at positions idx and match.
```